# Gmapping failed in long corridor using Navigation Stack

Tags: slam, navigation, p3dx, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I used P3DX with Hokuyo URG-04LX limiting range to only 3 metres and gave the odometry data to Gmapping as well. I have problem in using Gmapping in long corridor where the feature look the same.  For example, the left and the right side of robot is just the straight line. When I do Gmapping, even it walk through these parallel straight line for long time, it think it's in the same place and not move at all in gmapping in rviz. The map will update when it found something like doors. Thus, the robot walk for about 5-6 metres long until finding the doors but the map is 1-2 metres long.

How to fix this? or It's hard to do slam in the long corridor without distinct feature?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12427/gmapping-failed-in-long-corridor-using-navigation-stack/) by [ParNurZeal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1210/parnurzeal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2011-12-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

long, featureless corridors generally pose problems to SLAM, especially when the range of the laser sensor is limited since the scanmatching might fail in such cases.

Do you have the same problem when not limiting the range of the Hokuyo?

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2011-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anas](https://answers.ros.org/users/736/anas/) on 2012-01-09**:
Any solution ? I have the same problem here !

**Comment by [ParNurZeal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1210/parnurzeal/) on 2012-01-02**:
I see. Have we had any solution to that yet? Could you suggest some?

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-12-21**:
The URG-04 has a guaranteed range of 4m (may be able to detect up to 5.6m), so it won't help much anyways.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2012-05-13**:
Hope someone will still see this question... I'm experiencing exactly the same problem, and I have no solution too. What I wonder is that we should be able to instruct gmapping to not make "big jumps" that clearly contradict odometry, but just minor corrections, even lower scan matching score.